# Automatic download of Azure ServiceTags via php

Tags: php, azure, curl

I need to download Azure Public ServiceTag JSON from a PHP script. Unfortunately manual steps are required for the download (AWS offers direct download of json file with their networks).

The download link is following: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=57064

Hopefully, some has an idea of how follow the download link..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below [Service Tags -list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/servicetags/list) REST API End Point :

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Network/locations/{location}/serviceTags?api-version=2020-05-01
```

Suggestion of REST API, because you wanted to invoke from the PHP. You will have to pass the authorization header.

**Other Programmatical Approach**

[Get-AzNetworkServiceTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/Get-AzNetworkServiceTag?view=azps-2.8.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-2.3.2) Powershell Commandlet

```
$serviceTags = Get-AzNetworkServiceTag -Location eastus2
```

[az network list-service-tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_list_service_tags)  Azure CLI Commandlet

```
az network list-service-tags --location
                             [--subscription
```

]

Comment: @Risker - Did the above help ?

Answer (score 0):

if you can do this with proper api's like in @Satya V's answer, it's a much better solution than web scraping, but if you don't have access to use the apis (seems you need a `subscriptionId`, whatever that is, to use the api),

you can grab the download link with the XPath `//a[contains(.,'click here to download manually')]`

this seems to work:

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_URL=>"https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=57064",
    // setting CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to emptystring enables the cookie engine.
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE=>"",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
));
$html=curl_exec($ch);
$domd=new DOMDocument();
@$domd->loadHTML($html);
$xp=new DOMXPath($domd);
$download_url = $xp->query("//a[contains(.,'click here to download manually')]")->item(0)->getAttribute("href");
//var_dump($download_url);
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>0,
    CURLOPT_URL=>$download_url
));
curl_exec($ch);
```